Integral from trigonometric to contour integration



    
    
    Math Integral
    
    


We start with the original integral:
$$
2ak\rho \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{x - a \cos(\theta)}{(x - a \cos(\theta))^2 + (y - a \sin(\theta))^2} \, d\theta
$$
This integral can be transformed into a contour integral:
$$
\frac{k\rho}{i(yi - x)} \oint \frac{2x - az^2 - a}{z \left(z - \frac{a}{x - yi}\right)\left(z - \frac{x + iy}{a}\right)} \, dz
$$
where the contour is taken around $$ z = 1$$
I do know that it can be either be $$ z = 0, z = \frac{a}{x-yi} $$ or the option being $$ z = 0, z = \frac{x+iy}{a} $$ but not which one should I choose to be the correct answer.
Also, $$ x,y,\rho,k,a $$ are all constants

yes, x is independent of θ

Maybe you didnt understand , i think x and y are variables or if they are constant please edit your question use different notations for those constants.

x and y are constants

$z=0$ is of course a singularity for other singularity you have to know some conditions on constans, because for some cases they might not be inside contour , example if $a=1$  and $x+iy$ inside your contour then $\frac{1}{x-iy}$ is not inside the contour ,if  of course any singularity ly on unit circle you cant use this method.  singularities depending upon the constants . Here nothing is specified so you can consider the cases to solve this question.

Would you think the original integral has to be solved a different method?

Other ways would become tedious if you try, so all the best for other methods
